# How to remove dash (-) from string with regex except between numbers & words in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to remove dashes, underscores & extra spaces from a string.

Below is the code I tried :

```
public class Hello {

   public static void main(String args[]) {


          String blogName = "ABCD            __________________________________________________                      Size:      1234-5678 BAR                     8956-7896       ----------           CAR                     8756-2365";

          String nameWithProperSpacing = blogName.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll("_", ""); 

          System.out.println( nameWithProperSpacing );
    }
}
```

I don't want it to remove them from between words & numbers, though. For example my current code changes 8956-7896 to 89567896.

The output I want :

```
ABCD Size:1234-5678 BAR 8956-7896 CAR 8756-2365
```

Comment: Can you give some examples like input vs output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need search with lookahead and lookbehind

```
      String nameWithProperSpacing = blogName
              .replaceAll("(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])[-_](?![a-zA-Z0-9])", "") ///No -_ not inside a word
              .replaceAll("\\s+", " "); /// only 1 space between words
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be simply done by (Keep single dash, remove multiple dashes):

```
blogName.replaceAll("\\-(\\-)+","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not pretty but works with your example:

```
.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
            .replaceAll("--", "").replaceAll("__", "").replaceAll(" _", "")
            .replaceAll("_ ", "").replaceAll(" -", "").replaceAll("- ", "")
            .replaceAll("  ", " ").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
String nameWithProperSpacing = blogName.replaceAll("([^A-Za-z0-9])(\\-|\\s|_)+", "$1 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with non-word boundaries `\B` to remove them, but to do that you have to remove underscores first:

```
String nameWithProperSpacing = blogName.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll("_+", "").replaceAll("\\B-+|-+\\B", "");
```